# In triangle, ABC, angle ABC = 90deg and CD is angle bisector of angle ACB which meets side AB at D. if AD = 4cm, BD = 3cm. find the CD?

Tags: geometry

I have the diagram, but unable to find the value.[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

As you found out from Angle Bisector Theorem: $${CA\over CB}= {AD\over BD} ={4\over 3} \implies CA = 4t \;\wedge \; CB = 3t$$ By the Pythagorean Theorem, you then have: $$16t^2 = 7^2+9t^2$$ Can you finish solving it now?